# how to return object if the value is equal to multiple or values mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to get object details with 5 parameters , i need to return object if any one matches it .

keys -

```
genre1:{type:String},
genre2:{type:String},
genre3:{type:String},
genre4:{type:String},
genre5:{type:String},
```

i am sending 5 keys values from frontend , i need to return if any values is equal to field names

code -

```
app.get("/genre-content",async function (req,res) {
let head_genre1 = req.headers.genre1
let head_genre2 = req.headers.genre2
let head_genre3 = req.headers.genre3
let head_genre4 = req.headers.genre4
let head_genre5 = req.headers.genre5
let options =  head_genre1 || head_genre2 || head_genre3 || head_genre4 || head_genre5
let model = await Movies.find({genre1: options , genre2:options , genre3:options , 
genre4:options , genre5:options })
  return res.json(model)
})
```

please give me a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You can mongoose `.or()` - [link for how $or works in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
let model = await Movies.find().or([{
        genre1: head_genre1
    },
    {
        genre2: head_genre2
    },
    {
        genre3: head_genre3
    },
    {
        genre4: head_genre4
    },
    {
        genre5: head_genre5
    },
]).exec();
```